# Uninstalling Apache Geronimo Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, geronimo

How do I uninstall Apache Geronimo Adapter Eclipse Plugin?

Look the prints of my Eclipse. I've tried deleting some IBM jars from plugin folder but without success.

Using Eclipse plugin form, I can't find the Geronimo Adapter plugin to remove too.

The Images:

[image: Menu]

[image: Plugins]

Answer (score 2):

You should find it on the `Features` or at least `Plug-ins` tab  in the `Installation details`-Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to work for me was:

1. Remove all JARs named org.apache.geronimo.* from the eclipse/plugins dir.
2. Remove all subdirs named org.apache.geronimo.* from the same dir.
3. Remove all subdirs named org.apache.geronimo.* from the .metadata dir.

This comes without warranties of any kind. Close Eclipse and backup your eclipse and .metadata dirs before trying this!

If the above isn't working, you might just be able to live with Customize Perspective... -> Menu Visibility and remove the check.